# How to change jwplayer configuration through javascript

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I have a configured jwplayer that has options like this:

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer('player');

playerInstance.setup({
    mediaid: "...",
    image: "...",
    title: "...",
    playlist: [{
        ...
    }],
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    aspectratio: "400:157",
});
```

How do I change the `aspectratio` option programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
  stretching: "uniform",
  stretching: "exactfit",
  stretching: "fill",
  stretching: "none"
```

JW Player [Documentation](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-player-configuration-reference#section-setup-options)